# How to generate pdf using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I have tried using dompdf. The following is controller in the Codeigniter

```
function get_pdf( )
{
$this->load->library('Pdf');
$this->pdf->load_view('report.php' );
$this->pdf->load_html('report.php','',true);
$this->pdf->render();
$this->pdf->stream("welcome.pdf");
}
```

The data in report.php

```js
 
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
      
   
   
    
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $u+"get",
                data: {
                  
                  role:"report",
                   },

                datatype: "json",
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function(result) {
                   var result = $.parseJSON(result);
                     for (var result in syncx) {

                    $("#tta tbody").append("<tr ><td class='cyan'>"+x+"</td><td>"+syncx[x].total+ "</td> </tr>");
                          
                      }
                   
                       Morris.Line({
                element: 'total-line',
                data: source,
                behaveLikeLine: true,
               parseTime : false, 
                xkey: 'x',
                ykeys: [ 'totol'],
                labels: [  'total'],
                pointFillColors: ['#707f9b'],
                pointStrokeColors: ['#ffaaab'],
                lineColors: ['#f26c4f', '#00a651', '#00bff3'],
                redraw: true 
            });

                }
}
                          });

  
 });

  

 
  
 
<body>
   <div class="row ">
     
      
          <div id="responsive" class=" ">
        <h4  > Record</h4>
        <div class=" ">
          <div id="flip-scroll" class="card">
            <p> </p>
            <table id="tta"   >
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>x</th>
                    <th>Total </th>
                  
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody> </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

     
       </div>

      
    
    <div class="col  ">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <div  id="total-line"></div>
          <span class="card-title"> </span>
          
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">   <p>Total</p>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 
 
  

</body>
```

The pdf report is generated but only html data was there. The ajax and jquery data was missing. No graph was generated and table has no data.What should I do here to generate the complete report with graph and ajax data in the table complete. Here the view is fetched as it is but the data which is fetched from the ajax all is  missing.

EDIT: Please suggest something else which can be suitable to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
//File name
$filename = "Whatever-you-wish";

//Data can be any variables that you want to pass it on to the view.If you don't have anything to pass, just add null to the 2nd parameter.
$html = $this->load->view('sample',$data, true);  

//load library. I assume you have already uploaded the dom files under  application/library folder
$this->load->library('pdf');

//Intitialize dompdf object
$dompdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf();

//add view
$dompdf->load_html($html);

//Render the PDF
$dompdf->render();

//If you have any options to add it to this function
$options = new Dompdf\Options();
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', TRUE);

//Default paper size
$dompdf->set_paper('DEFAULT_PDF_PAPER_SIZE', 'portrait');

//Output the result
$output = $dompdf->output();

//Save it to the folder. Folder has to be created outside the application folder.
file_put_contents('your-folder-name/' . $filename . '.pdf', $output);
```

Hope this could work. Thank You.